# table with a large root inside (trig mnemonics)

Tags: tables, alignment, root

I'd like to reproduce the following trigonometry mnemonic table on LaTeX for my high school students. I tried a table within a table but the columns didn't align correctly, they were more cramped inside the root.
[image]

Is there a way, besides manual spacing, to place the columns in an aligned fashion?

Thanks in advance, be safe! cheers from Chile.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to the TeX.SE. You can create your picture using a fast tool that give a long code in `TikZ`: see this example.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}


\begin{document}


\begin{figure}[!htb] 
\centering
\tikzset{every picture/.style={line width=0.75pt}} %set default line width to 0.75pt        

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.75pt,y=0.75pt,yscale=-1,xscale=1]
%uncomment if require: \path (0,400); %set diagram left start at 0, and has height of 400

%Straight Lines [id:da7273616003837933] 
\draw [line width=1.5]    (154.5,123) -- (169.5,174) ;
%Straight Lines [id:da23429916290670527] 
\draw [line width=1.5]    (191.5,79) -- (169.5,174) ;
%Straight Lines [id:da2605957224293076] 
\draw [line width=1.5]    (191.5,79) -- (449.5,79) ;
%Straight Lines [id:da8643007318383729] 
\draw    (190.5,173) -- (446.5,173) ;

% Text Node
\draw (299,184.4) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]  [font=\Large]  {$2$};
% Text Node
\draw (111,101.4) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]  [font=\Large,color={rgb, 255:red, 74; green, 144; blue, 226 }  ,opacity=1 ]  {$\sin$};
% Text Node
\draw (110,140) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]  [font=\Large,color={rgb, 255:red, 208; green, 2; blue, 27 }  ,opacity=1 ]  {$\cos$};
% Text Node
\draw (210,103.4) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]  [font=\Large,color={rgb, 255:red, 74; green, 144; blue, 226 }  ,opacity=1 ]  {$0$};
% Text Node
\draw (262,103.4) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]  [font=\Large,color={rgb, 255:red, 74; green, 144; blue, 226 }  ,opacity=1 ]  {$1$};
% Text Node
\draw (315,103.4) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]  [font=\Large,color={rgb, 255:red, 74; green, 144; blue, 226 }  ,opacity=1 ]  {$2$};
% Text Node
\draw (370,104.4) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]  [font=\Large,color={rgb, 255:red, 74; green, 144; blue, 226 }  ,opacity=1 ]  {$3$};
% Text Node
\draw (421,104.4) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]  [font=\Large,color={rgb, 255:red, 74; green, 144; blue, 226 }  ,opacity=1 ]  {$4$};
% Text Node
\draw (210,139.4) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]  [font=\Large,color={rgb, 255:red, 208; green, 2; blue, 27 }  ,opacity=1 ]  {$4$};
% Text Node
\draw (262,139.4) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]  [font=\Large,color={rgb, 255:red, 208; green, 2; blue, 27 }  ,opacity=1 ]  {$3$};
% Text Node
\draw (315,139.4) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]  [font=\Large,color={rgb, 255:red, 208; green, 2; blue, 27 }  ,opacity=1 ]  {$2$};
% Text Node
\draw (370,140.4) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]  [font=\Large,color={rgb, 255:red, 208; green, 2; blue, 27 }  ,opacity=1 ]  {$1$};
% Text Node
\draw (421,140.4) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]  [font=\Large,color={rgb, 255:red, 208; green, 2; blue, 27 }  ,opacity=1 ]  {$0$};
% Text Node
\draw (208,46.4) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]  [font=\Large,color={rgb, 255:red, 74; green, 144; blue, 226 }  ,opacity=1 ]  {$0^{\circ} $};
% Text Node
\draw (254,46.4) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]  [font=\Large,color={rgb, 255:red, 74; green, 144; blue, 226 }  ,opacity=1 ]  {$30^{\circ} $};
% Text Node
\draw (360,46.4) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]  [font=\Large,color={rgb, 255:red, 74; green, 144; blue, 226 }  ,opacity=1 ]  {$60^{\circ} $};
% Text Node
\draw (414,47.4) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]  [font=\Large,color={rgb, 255:red, 74; green, 144; blue, 226 }  ,opacity=1 ]  {$90^{\circ} $};
% Text Node
\draw (307,46.4) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]  [font=\Large,color={rgb, 255:red, 74; green, 144; blue, 226 }  ,opacity=1 ]  {$45^{\circ} $};


\end{tikzpicture}

\caption{Table}
\end{figure}
\end{document}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This is very nice.